# Query documents that contains all values in nested array Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to query documents where the nested array contains all of the elements passed in the query.

The index stores groups and each group has a list of members. I want to query all the groups that contains the given members.

Mapping:

```
"properties" : {
   "members" : {
      "type" : "nested",
      "properties" : {
         "name" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
         }
       }
    },
    "name" : {
        "type" : "text"
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Example content:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "group 1",
    "members" : [
      {
        "name" : "alice"
      },
      {
        "name" : "bob"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "group 2",
    "members" : [
      {
        "name" : "alice"
      },
      {
        "name" : "foo"
      },
      {
        "name" : "bob"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "group 3",
    "members" : [
      {
        "name" : "foo"
      },
      {
        "name" : "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I find all groups that have both "alice" and "foo" as members?

I have tried the following query but it returns nothing:

```
GET /group/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "members",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {"members.name": "alice"}},
            {"match": {"members.name": "foo"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried with `term` instead of `match` but it gives no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the nested within a must clause. Like this:

```
GET /group/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "nested": {
           "path": "members",
           "query": {
             "term": {
               "members.name": {
                 "value": "alice"
               }
             }
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "nested": {
           "path": "members",
           "query": {
             "term": {
               "members.name": {
                 "value": "foo"
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```